# How to handle missing/unresolved modules when bundling?

Tags: javascript, webpack

I'm trying to bundle an old requirejs app using webpack. The application works fine. When I execute webpack, it displays a number of errors each complaining about some missing modules (these libraries were loaded with bower). Below are some of the module it is complaining about and the source library:

- localforage:

  - localforage.js: Cannot resolve module 'promise'
  - driver/localstorage.js: Cannot resolve module 'localforageSerializer'.
  - driver/websql.js      : same as above
- showdown   : Cannot resolve module 'fs'

Also, it fails to resolve relative require statements like

```
./../utils/serializer, ./drivers/indexeddb, ./drivers/localstorage and ./drivers/websql.
```

I'm tempted to try editing the files to see if I can correct these but want to know if there is a good way of correcting this.

I tried using `require("imports?require=>__webpack_require__!localforage");` but then it fails saying `./drivers/indexeddb` does not exist.

PS:
I managed to get it to work by doing the following

`localforage` was fixed using `resolve.alias`. `localforage` was pointed to the `.../src/localforage` (used to be the dist version). `localforageSerializer` was added and it points to `.../src/util/serializer`.

For `showdown`, I just edited the code. I'm sure it is not the right thing to do though.

Comment: Can you add examples of AMD imports you are using? I'm particularly interested in ones importing `localforage` and `showdown`.

Comment: i'm not really following. I'm using knockout and so localforage and showdown are required by some of my components. Other libraries I'm using include semantic, toastr, c3, d3, moment and jquery-scrollto.

Comment: I found this [link](http://npm.taobao.org/package/webpack-localforage). Seems to be a fix for the localforage issue though it does not help address the general issue.

Comment: I see. You can try to define a [resolve.alias](https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#resolve-alias) for the problematic dependencies. The alias would match to dependency name and map to a dist build. That way you avoid using Node version with problematic deps like fs. Esp. showdown works differently based on context.

Comment: Ok so if the dependency is not available, I'll have to first add them. In the case where they are already part of the main library but webpack is failing to recognize them, won't that bloat the size of the bundle?

Comment: Can you list the direct dependencies you are having problems with? I could have a better look at the situation that way and provide perhaps a better solution.

Comment: At the moment, it is just `localforage` and `showdown`. I have a component that displays questions and they in in markdown so depends on `showdown`. When it is over, another component is called that saves the data using `localforage`. Those are the only two places where these libraries are used.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77373/discussion-between-ritcoder-and-bebraw).